# Multiline mode-line using dynamic generated text images

Tags: mode-line, images

I've been doing experiments at displaying static text images in the mode-line using Imagemagick to generate the image (see below). I would like now to generate such an image in a dynamic way, providing information from within Emacs.
For example, I could display the current major mode or the cursor line/column (might be slow).

My question is how to dynamically generate the image according to the provided information (e.g. how to call and pass arguments to Imagemagick). Displaying line/column using image Imagemagick might very slow but still, I would like to try.

[image: Multilines mode-line with static text image (through imagemagick)]

Imagemagick command used for the screenshot:

```
convert -antialias -background none -fill white -family Roboto -weight regular -gravity southeast -size 64x42 -pointsize 20 label:"Emacs\nv26.3" label.png
```

And in the modeline (header line in my case):

```
(propertize " " 'display (create-image "~/label.png" 'png nil :ascent 90 ))
```

Comment: Please pose only one question per question. Please edit, simplifying to a single question, and post your other question separately. Thx.

Comment: You can look into nyan-cat for inspiration. Bsically, add an `eval` form into `mode-line-format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a [solution](https://gist.github.com/rougier/f65264c0ca5e0dde22dfc684b5ea1667) using SVG.

[image]